# unable to use cron tab

Tags: cron, crontab

I am using crontab on unix shell

using putty to connect to unix server

unable to use crontab

i scheduled crontab at say * * * * * cat > new < new1

doesnt work
I works only in home directory of user only not in other directory

can you help me in this

Comment: Please rephrase your question giving more information. What is the exact crontab line? How do you use crontab (crontab -e or you modify a specific file)? Have you tried that command? Have you tried putting it in an executable script? Is there any error in the logfiles? ...etc

Answer (score 1):

Try putting full paths for the filenames.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the system-wide crontab in `/etc/crontab` or the user's crontab (`crontab -e`)? If the latter, does the user have write access to that "other directory"?